# can't load submodules when I call python in cmd

Tags: python, import, attributeerror

As a demo for the problem, I use this very simple script (debug_only.py):

```
from absl import app
from absl import flags

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_string('config', None, 'Path to the experiment configuration file.')

def main(argv):
    del argv
    print(FLAGS.config)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(main)
```

I have no problem to run it in jupyter notebook by calling main, but I got the following error when I call it in terminal by "python debug_only.py":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "projects/hecktor2022/only_debug.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from absl import app
File "/home/qian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 38, in \<module\>
from absl import logging
File "/home/qian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/logging/__init__.py", line 99, in \<module\>
from absl.logging import converter
File "/home/qian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/logging/converter.py", line 49, in \<module\>
STANDARD_CRITICAL = logging.CRITICAL
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'CRITICAL'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in \<module\>
from apport.report import Report
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in \<module\>
import apport.fileutils
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 12, in \<module\>
import os, glob, subprocess, os.path, time, pwd, sys, requests_unixsocket
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py", line 1, in \<module\>
import requests
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in \<module\>
import urllib3
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in \<module\>
from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 29, in \<module\>
from .connection import (
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 41, in \<module\>
from .util.ssl\_ import (
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 20, in \<module\>
from .retry import Retry
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 20, in \<module\>
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "projects/hecktor2022/only_debug.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from absl import app
File "/home/qian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 38, in \<module\>
from absl import logging
File "/home/qian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/logging/__init__.py", line 99, in \<module\>
from absl.logging import converter
File "/home/qian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/logging/converter.py", line 49, in \<module\>
STANDARD_CRITICAL = logging.CRITICAL
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'CRITICAL'
```

It seems to me that python doesn't load the submodules correctly when it loads a library (absl in this case). I tried other packages like argparse, but got the similar AttributeErrors. I have no idea how to solve the problem and doesn't understand why it would occur in terminal but not in jupyter notebook.

Comment: jupyter is running in a venv, and I can load "from absl import app" in the interactive python mode. I run the script in the same venv. Running "pip list | grep absl" returns "absl-py 1.4.0"

Comment: I see in the traceback all your problems are from the module "logging." Do you maybe have a file called "logging.py" in this folder? It might be intercepting everything that's trying to use the standard library of the same name. Try renaming it to mylogging.py or something like that.